# Addresses of a variable and an array element conflict

Tags: c, arrays

I've experienced an issue which comes so weird to me, addresses of an `unsigned int` and array element is exactly same. I tried to use `malloc`, it couldn't go for it. Used `realloc`, it didn't work because there is no `malloc`. Used both, same issue continues. What do you think, am I missing something really easy? I'm new to C, I managed to understand the issue with using breakpoints in Xcode.

Here is the code block;

```
int stocksMain(unsigned int itemQuantity)
{
    if (itemQuantity == 0) {
        getErrorManifest(501);
        return -1;
    }

    else {
        unsigned int itemStock[] = {0};

        char line[BUFSIZ];

        clearInputBuffer();

        memset(&line, 0, sizeof(line));

        printf("%s\n", "Enter the stocks of items:");

        printf("Address of itemQuantity: %p\nAddress of itemStock[1]: %p\n", &itemQuantity, &itemStock[1]);

        malloc(itemQuantity);

        printf("New address of itemQuantity: %p\nNew address of itemStock[1]: %p\n", &itemQuantity, &itemStock[1]);

        for (int i = 0; i < itemQuantity; ++i) {

            printf("#%d:  ", i + 1);

            fgets(line, BUFSIZ, stdin);

            if ( (line[0] == 'f') || (line[0] == 'F') ) {
                //doStockOfItemIsInfinite
            }

            else {
                sscanf(line, "%u", &itemStock[i]);
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}   //end stocksMain
```

Output:

```
Enter the stocks of items:
Address of itemQuantity: 0x7fff5fbff7c0
Address of itemStock[1]: 0x7fff5fbff7c0
New address of itemQuantity: 0x7fff5fbff7c0
New address of itemStock[1]: 0x7fff5fbff7c0
#1:  Program ended with exit code: 9
```

Comment: `malloc(itemQuantity);` just like that, no storing its return value or anything? did you even **read** the documentation of `malloc()` or a tutorial on memory management?

Comment: Once I've used this function to create VLA, I knew it superficially.

Comment: you can't create VLAs using `malloc()`.

Comment: @user3477950 Yeah I know, it was something I read in stackoverflow.com but after I learnt it is impossible.

Comment: @Instigator: You do not have an VLA, because its size is exactly one. A VLA would look like `int itemStock[itemQuantity]`.

Comment: Style comment: with the `return` at the end of the first `if`, it would be better to leave what is currently the `else` block as 'the rest of the code' and unindented one level.  Yes, it is the 'else' operation, but there's no benefit (and minor harm) in having the remaining code indented an unnecessary level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to capture the return value from `malloc()` in an appropriate pointer variable.

Also, the only valid element in `itemStock` is `itemStock[0]`.  You may generate the address `itemStock[1]` but you cannot legitimately access the data at that address.  In your case, the address `itemStock[1]` is the same as your simple variable `itemQuantity`; that's perfectly OK, but you can't rely on that being the behaviour.

I suspect you are after code somewhat like:

```
char line[BUFSIZ];
unsigned itemStock[itemQuantity];  // C99 or later VLA

clearInputBuffer();

printf("%s\n", "Enter the stocks of items:");
for (int i = 0; i < itemQuantity; ++i)
{
    printf("#%d:  ", i + 1);
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == 0)
        break;
    else if (line[0] == 'f' || line[0] == 'F')
    {
        //doStockOfItemIsInfinite
    }
    else if (sscanf(line, "%u", &itemStock[i]) != 1)
        ...report error...
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
char line[BUFSIZ];
unsigned *itemStock = malloc(itemQuantity * sizeof(*itemStock));
if (itemStock == 0)
   ...memory allocation failed...do not continue...
clearInputBuffer();

printf("%s\n", "Enter the stocks of items:");
for (int i = 0; i < itemQuantity; ++i)
{
    printf("#%d:  ", i + 1);
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == 0)
        break;
    else if (line[0] == 'f' || line[0] == 'F')
    {
        //doStockOfItemIsInfinite
    }
    else if (sscanf(line, "%u", &itemStock[i]) != 1)
        ...report error...
}
```

The difference is that with `malloc()`, you must somewhere explicitly use `free(itemStock);`, but you can return `itemStock` to a calling function. By contrast, with the local VLA, you cannot use the variable after the block in which it is defined is exited (so you don't have to free it), but you can only pass it to called functions; you cannot return it.

Which is more appropriate depends on what you're going to do with the array after the loop finishes.

Comment: So the solution to my problem is using malloc?

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, beyond you aren't sure what you're doing.  What are you really trying to do?  Create a dynamic array for `itemStock` so you can read many values into it?

Answer (score 1):

itemStock is an array with a single element. Therefore, &itemStock [1] is a valid address, but can be equal to the address of a different object. In this case, it is. I have no idea what you think the call to malloc () is going to do. Nothing useful, I can tell you that much.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are new to C.

1. An array index starts with 0. Therefore `ìtemStock[1]` is the second element of an array that has 1 element. Because both arguments and locals are stored on the stack, you get by incident the address of the argument.
2. Please read something about the usage of `malloc`. There are enough tutorials in internet.

Comment: `s/is/can be/g`. there's no such thing as "the stack" in C; trying to explain undefined behavior is mostly pointless (especially in the case of modern optimizing compilers).

Comment: It absolutely is, and I go further: it is harmful, because it misleads a beginner who cannot qualify and categorize the (mis)information he faces.

Comment: It is not a misinformation, because this *is* the reason, why the addresses are equal. Even you cannot believe it, something can happen, even it is not part of the standard. Not being a part of a standard does not mean, non existing. He never wanted to take any advantage out of this behavior, but simply wanted to know the reason.

Comment: Let me explain you why this is misinformation. It's not that I don't *believe* it. Unless you know the very implementation/platform/machine/compiler OP's code runs on, you **cannot possibly** assume **anything** about its implementation details. Function calls and local variables don't have to be implemented using a stack. Dynamic memory allocation needn't be implemented using a heap. "both arguments and locals are stored on the stack" is not even correct on CPUs which do have a stack since the arguments and local variables may be stored in registers as well...

Comment: So, you are building on strong, and potentially wrong, assumptions. Furthermore, since OP's code has undefined behavior, the compiler has **all rights** to do every sort of funny and unexpected stuff with his code (anywhere and at anytime). This **includes** storing a local variable in a register and then making the `&` operator yield a bogus address which points not-even-god-knows-where.

Comment: I did not assume that this works on every platform. I did not say that he can assume it. I know that it will be different on many platforms. But it is the reason for the equality on *his* platform. He asked for the reason on *his* platform, he did not ask for a defined behavior on any platform. I have read the standard dozens of times for a book. I know it.